# Angular upgrade issues

Tags: angular, webpack

We are trying to upgrade angular version from 7.2 to 12.x. We have followed steps on the document available on angular.io. We have updated our module libraries also with the latest ones. Now when we started application we encountered the errors as below:

```
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MetadataDtsModuleScopeResolver.resolve (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\dependency.js:47:69)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:515:51)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:365:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)

[36m./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MetadataDtsModuleScopeResolver.resolve (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\dependency.js:47:69)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:515:51)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:365:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MetadataDtsModuleScopeResolver.resolve (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\dependency.js:47:69)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:515:51)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:365:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\workspace\1.3-uiux\NextGeneUI\nextgeneui-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:519:29)



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

---

We have tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling node_modules, but these didn't help.

Please help.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nextgeneui-app",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/backbone": "^1.3.43",
    "@types/dagre": "^0.7.46",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.123",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.4",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "^12.1.1",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^1.3.2",
    "angular-resize-event": "^3.0.2",
    "angular2-highlight-js": "^9.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.30.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.0.3",
    "bootstrap-duallistbox": "^3.0.6",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-progressbar": "^0.9.0",
    "bootstrap-slider": "^10.6.1",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "d3": "^5.9.1",
    "d3-graphviz": "^2.6.1",
    "d3-hexbin": "^0.2.2",
    "diff2html": "^3.4.13",
    "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "highlight.js": "^11.3.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.3",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
    "jointjs": "^3.4.4",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
    "jquery-ui-npm": "^1.12.0",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.0",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "^1.4.1",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^10.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.7",
    "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "^0.1.3",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-logger": "^5.0.4",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
    "plotly.js": "^2.8.3",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^12.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "resumablejs": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "Select2": "^3.5.7",
    "smartadmin-plugins": "^1.0.22",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "vis": "^4.21.0-EOL",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^12.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,    
    "allowJs": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "es2020",
        "typeRoots": [ 
              "./types", "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
      "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems with updating Angular have been resolved by installing the current stable version of Node (version 16 as of 12/2021).
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/issues/1289

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @TazHinkle, we do have node v16.13.0